# Correlating aggregated values between groups

Tags: correlation, spss, spatial, normality-assumption, aggregation

I am currently analysing data from household surveys in 27 Indian villages in 7 states, with about 30 cases in each village (807 in total). The aim is to find relationships between various factors and the quality of water supply households are receiving.
Overall service level (after some of other steps) is reported on a ordinal scale with 5 steps from 'no service' (0) to 'high' (4). To give each village a single score, the percentage of households that get at least 'basic' (2) service in each village is calculated.

Now I am interested in correlating for example the median village income or percentage of minority religious groups as independent variable with this percentage of households receiving acceptable service as the dependent variable.
I have researched and read about the ecological fallacy and am well aware that results from this test wouldn't allow me to conclude that individual households get better service because of X. But comparing data on a village level conceptually makes sense, as one can imagine that the overall wealth in a village might be more important for a water supply system than being one rich individual in an otherwise poor village. Anyway, coming back to the actual statistics, reading about this and the other questions I could find here didn't really answer my two main questions:

- Can I treat percentages of ordinal or categorical data (e.g. percentage with acceptable supply, percentage minority religion) as a scale variable?
- Which correlation should I use? Both the overall service level and Median income fail the Shapiro-Wilk test for normality, so am I better off using a non-parametric correlation (I was thinking Spearman's rho) than Pearson?